# Cannot create package IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

I am attempting to create a package for my project in IntelliJ IDEA. I am naming the package 'com.mydomain.switch' Switch being the project name, but as soon as I type 'switch' it shows an error.

The only thing I can think of is that 'switch' is a Java keyword, is this the case? and if so what can I do about it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: @NimChimpsky the question is not about switch keyword. it is about packagename 'com.mydomain.switch'.

Comment: @krishnaTelgave oh really ?  I wonder why the switch package name doesn't work then ?

Answer (score 6):

When creating a package named switch, IntelliJ IDEA displays the following error message:

> Not a valid package name, it would be impossible to create a class inside

So, the message is quite clear. What you can do about it: use another name. The possibilities are infinite.

Here is the list of reserved keywords, that can't be used as identifiers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9

Comment: Is there any convention for naming classes where the desired name is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You probably had a space after the packagename.

Intellij will give that error if the packagename ends with a space.